# Blender render is not right

Tags: rendering, rigid-body-simulation

1. i've imported my HDRI and my objects
2. i've created a rig with RBC (the addon that simplifies car simulation)
3. recorded cache from RBC
4. tried to render but it's not the same

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xkhv.jpg)

[render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XCb0.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)